# (P ∧ Q) → D, is the statement true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, natural-deduction

```
D = a decision
P = a piece of information
Q = another piece of information

a piece of information can change a decision, P → D
another piece of information can not change a decision, ¬(→)

Then both pieces of information together can change the decision?

(→)∧¬(→)
```

Is the statement true? I mean is below statement true,

> Both pieces of information together can change the decision, D

#### Why Its creating confusion to me?

When a mind gets both piece of information, Things getting confused!

```
P = a piece of information
Q = another piece of information
```

So,

```
P ∧ Q = Both pieces of information together, thus
P ∧ Q → D = Both pieces of information together can change the decision
```

But,

```
(P → D) ∧ ¬(Q → D) is not same as (P ∧ Q), right?
```

Anyone can clarify what am I missing?

Comment: No, it is not… Check with truth table.

Comment: Why the ref to Natural Deduction ?

Comment: "Both pieces of information together can change the decision, D " This is true, but it is not equivalent to $[(P\rightarrow D) \land \neg (Q\rightarrow D)]\rightarrow D$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog can you modify the equations for me please? I am on mobile now.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Also how does it become true? Elaborating your answer will be helpful.

Comment: @Sazzad Both pieces together would be $P\land Q$, so if both together can change the decision, it would be $P\land Q\to D$. However, judging from the wording this is about decision making, hence I would think this is about *gaining information* to change *the state of the world*. Probably that is better described using some kind of dynamic epistemic logic, instead of propositional. Elaborating your question would be helpful (why do you have this question, what is the context?)

Comment: @Vsotvep I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ultimately depends on interpretation, especially if this is not a question about strict rules of logic, but instead a question about practical decision making.

The difference between $P\land Q\to D$ and $(P\to D)\land \lnot(Q\to D)$ is that (translated in your words) the first states that "the information of $P$ and $Q$ together will change the decision", while the second states "the information of $P$ changes the decision, and the information of $Q$ does not".

From a propositional standpoint, this means that $P\land Q\to D$ is true whenever $D$ is true or either $P$ or $Q$ is not true. On the other hand, $(P\to D)\land \lnot(Q\to D)$ is true whenever $P\to D$ is true (i.e. $P$ is false or $D$ is true) and $Q\to D$ is false (i.e. both $D$ is true and $Q$ is false).

In particular, we see that the second sentence needs $D$ to be true, while the first one does not.

---

However, as this is about information changing a decision, things should not really be interpreted using propositional logic. There is a clear causality between the events of $P$ and $Q$ becoming known and the making of the decision $D$, and this causality needs to be described properly.

The problem is that a decision does not have a truth value, but is an action instead. Similarly, although information can be true or false, the act of receiving new information is an action, and not a proposition.

Therefore, to properly model this kind of situation, I would consider using [dynamic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_logic_(modal_logic)), or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. It helps.

Comment: An additional comment, saying that Q does not change the decision sounds more like it is not relevant to whether D or not. This is a kind of implication that is not material, so perhaps you might want to look into relevance logic additionally.